# Is saying "...no matter whether ..." OK or a redundancy or grammatically wrong?

Tags: grammaticality, redundancy

I look up the examples of "no matter" in some web dictionary and don't find a sentence containing "no matter whether". But in the examples of "whether" and "irrespective" I do see sentences "He's going to buy a house *whether* he gets married or not." and "He was one of those men to whom a girl's left hand is simply a girl's left hand, *irrespective of whether* it wears rings on its third finger or not." So is "no matter whether" OK or a redundancy or grammatically wrong? But if it's a redundancy, doesn't "irrespective of whether" (in the aforementioned sentence) sound like a redundancy, too (because using "whether" suffices to convey the idea) ? Should I just use "no matter" or "whether", instead of "no matter whether", in sentences of this type? Or either way is OK?

For example, is saying "The conclusion holds true *no matter whether* the proof is carried out through this formulation or that formulation." a redundancy or grammatically wrong? Should I just say "The conclusion holds true *whether* the proof is carried out through this formulation or that formulation." or "The conclusion holds true *no matter* the proof is carried out through this formulation or that formulation."? Or either of the three ways is OK?

Comment: [...in sentences like "No matter whether ..." **no matter** is not necessarily required, presumably because **whether** can function like **if**, e.g. "Whether Mary buys a dog or a cat, I'll throw it away"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22no+matter+is+not+necessarily+required%22). But I would say you seem to be assuming that "redundancy" is somehow undesirable. I'd say it's a normal, if not *necessary,* feature of all languages, not just English. I'd also say your final version is probably ungrammatical.

Comment: So saying sentences containing "no matter whether" is OK because it's grammatically correct even it's a redundancy? Also, which one do you mean by my final version?

Comment: I mean I don't like the version in your penultimate sentence above *(The conclusion holds true no matter the proof is carried out through this formulation or that formulation)*, because I think to be grammatically valid at all it should include ***whether*** or ***if***. But in both that sentence *and* the one in my example, a case can easily be made for saying they're actually *ambiguous* if you remove ***no matter***, so it's not simply redundant anyway.

Comment: OK, I think putting "no matter" in front of a clause without squeezing "whether" or "if" between them is probably grammatically incorrect. I made that kind of sentences because I just saw some examples in the web dictionary, such as "no matter the score, Mississippi football fans always win the tailgate." But what follows "no matter" here is a noun, not a clause. But I also saw the example "Football: Home is always where the heart lies no matter the fame says Neil Lennon; Northern Ireland v France." I don't understand  this sentence so don't know if what follows "no matter" here is a clause.

Comment: In your own question text you seem to imply that you understand ***no matter*** can be equated to ***irrespective of***. Do you still not understand your cited "home/fame" example after making the substitution there? Consider Google Books' claimed 45000 hits for [no matter the cost](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22no+matter+the+cost%22), where it may help to assume a "deleted" element such as ***what*** or ***how great*** after ***no matter***.

Comment: I actually don't understand what "the fame says Neil Lennon" means though I feel it should a clause. Then if it's a clause, why isn't there a conjunction between "no matter" and "the fame says Neil Lennon"? I don't see the relavance of this question to replacing "no matter" with "irrespective of".

Comment: I see in http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/no-matter-whether.1030270/ someone asked a similar question as me and the response is that using "no matter whether" is OK and using "whether" is of weaker sentiment than "no matter whether" in that given example. So If I don't intend to express sentiment but just want to express logic, like in my example "The conclusion holds true (no matter) whether the proof is carried out through this formulation or that formulation.", using "no matter whether" or "whether" makes no difference as far as the conveyed meaning is concerned?

Comment: It's meaningless to ask what "the fame says Neil Lennon" means. Those words just happen to appear consecutively in your cited example, which could just as easily have been written as *Neil Lennon says "Home is always where the heart lies no matter the fame"* - which just means *Home is where the heart is, **and being famous doesn't affect this truth***. You need to bear in mind that the two-word collocation ***no matter*** is something of a "fixed form", so there's a limit to how far you can take things with syntactic analysis.

Answer (score 4):

### Definitions

`no matter` - (adv) regardless of

`whether` - (conj) expressing a doubt or choice between alternatives

### Explanation

`No matter` emphasizes that which option you choose is not important.

`Whether` informs the listener that multiple options are about to be presented.

### Examples

`The conclusion holds true no matter whether the proof is carried out through this formulation or that formulation.` - Has emphasis from `no matter`

`The conclusion holds true whether the proof is carried out through this formulation or that formulation.` - Does not have emphasis from `no matter`

`The conclusion holds true no matter the proof is carried out through this formulation or that formulation.` - You can't say this. It is grammatically incorrect.

Comment: Is ``irrespective of" also an adverb and used in the same way as "`no matter"?